# JavasScript / jQuery Tic Tac Toe alert error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a beginner and making a very simple 2-player Tic Tac Toe game using HTML and JavaScript/jQuery. The alert for the winner pops up whenever any move is made, and I'm not sure why. Since I used an underscore as the default for each square on the board, right now the popup just says "_ Wins!"

I first created 9 buttons on the HTML page. Then I used JavaScript and jQuery to set up event listeners for clicking each button, and to replace the button with either an "X" or an "O", depending on who's turn it is. I'm pretty sure my `check` function is incorrect.

Can you please let me know where I went wrong?

```
var $squares = $('.square');
var sq1 = $squares[0];
var sq2 = $squares[1];
var sq3 = $squares[2];
var sq4 = $squares[3];
var sq5 = $squares[4];
var sq6 = $squares[5];
var sq7 = $squares[6];
var sq8 = $squares[7];
var sq9 = $squares[8];

var move = 0;
var emptySpaces = 9;

$squares.on("click", function() {
  if (move % 2 === 0) {
    $(this).val("X");
  } else {
    $(this).val("O");
  };
  move++;
  emptySpaces--;
  check();
});


function check() {

  if ((sq1.value === sq2.value) && (sq2.value === sq3.value) && (sq1.value !== "_")) {
    alert(sq1.value + " Wins!");
    reset();
  } else if ((sq4.value === sq5.value) && (sq5.value === sq6.value) && (sq4.value !== "_")) {
    alert(sq4.value + " Wins!");
    reset();
  } else if ((sq7.value === sq8.value) && (sq8.value === sq9.value) && (sq7.value !== "")) {
    alert(sq7.value + " Wins!");
    reset();
  } else if ((sq1.value === sq5.value) && (sq5.value === sq9.value) && (sq1.value !== "")) {
    alert(sq1.value + " Wins!");
    reset();
  } else if ((sq3.value === sq5.value) && (sq5.value === sq7.value) && (sq3.value !== "")) {
    alert(sq3.value + " Wins!");
    reset();
  } else if ((sq2.value === sq5.value) && (sq5.value === sq8.value) && (sq2.value !== "")) {
    alert(sq2.value + " Wins!");
    reset();
  } else if ((emptySpaces <= 0) && (complete() === true)) {
    alert("It's a tie.");
    reset();
  };
};

function complete() {
  if (sq1.value === "_" || sq2.value === "_" || sq3.value === "_" || sq4.value === "_" || sq5.value === "_" || sq6.value === "_" || sq7.value === "_" || sq8.value === "_" || sq9.value === "_") {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  };
};

function reset() {
  sq1.value = "_";
  sq2.value = "_";
  sq3.value = "_";
  sq4.value = "_";
  sq5.value = "_";
  sq6.value = "_";
  sq7.value = "_";
  sq8.value = "_";
  sq9.value = "_";
  move = 0;
  emptySpaces = 9;
};
```

Thanks.

Comment: check with this http://jsfiddle.net/NxFX6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried your code and did a small check. You are correct there is a little logical problem in you code.

I added a check to see if the value is `"_"`. Below is my code alteration.

```
function check() {

  if ((sq1.value === sq2.value) && (sq2.value === sq3.value) && (sq1.value !== "_")) {
      if(sq1.value!="_") { // Added check here
          alert(sq1.value + " Wins!");
          reset();
      }
  } else if ((sq4.value === sq5.value) && (sq5.value === sq6.value) && (sq4.value !== "_")) {
      if(sq4.value!="_") { // Added check here
          alert(sq4.value + " Wins!");
          reset();
      }
  } else if ((sq7.value === sq8.value) && (sq8.value === sq9.value) && (sq7.value !== "")) {
      if(sq7.value!="_") { // Added check here
          alert(sq7.value + " Wins!");
          reset();
      }
  } else if ((sq1.value === sq5.value) && (sq5.value === sq9.value) && (sq1.value !== "")) {
      if(sq1.value!="_") { // Added check here
          alert(sq1.value + " Wins!");
          reset();
      }
  } else if ((sq3.value === sq5.value) && (sq5.value === sq7.value) && (sq3.value !== "")) {
      if(sq3.value!="_") { // Added check here
          alert(sq3.value + " Wins!");
          reset();
      }
  } else if ((sq2.value === sq5.value) && (sq5.value === sq8.value) && (sq2.value !== "")) {
      if(sq2.value!="_") { // Added check here
          alert(sq2.value + " Wins!");
          reset();
      }
  } else if ((emptySpaces <= 0) && (complete() === true)) {
    alert("It's a tie.");
  };
};
```

**Reason:** Previously, since you were not checking the `"_"` value, it is resetting on every click. But ideally it should reset only when one of the players have won the game. So I checked if the game is won and then I reset the values.

I expect this should fix your problem. Let me know.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/Rdvd2/)**

Answer (score 0):

If these are `button` HTML elements, then you are accessing their value incorrectly.

You need to use `sq#.attr("value")` to access the value of the `button`.

Also, avoid naming variables with the prefix `$`. This is reserved for jQuery. Following that convention will avoid naming collisions.

**Edit:**
It would be even neater to use a JavaScript array for this. That way, you can dynamically make an X by Y size game without changing any code! Here's some code to get you started. The only part missing is to create the elements in the DOM and bind the events.

```
var ROW_SIZE = 3, COL_SIZE = 3;

var makeBoard = function() {
    var board = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < ROW_SIZE; i++) {
        board[i] = new Array();
        for (var j = 0; j < COL_SIZE; j++) {
            board[i][j] = -1;
        }
    }
    return board;
}

var check = function() {
    outer:
    for (var row = 0; row < ROW_SIZE; row++) { // check for a "row win"
        for (var col = 0; col < COL_SIZE - 1; col++) {
            if (board[row][col] != board[row + 1][col] || board[row][col] == -1)
                continue outer;
        }
        alert("Winner");
        return;
    }

    outer:
    for (var col = 0; col < COL_SIZE; col++) { // check for a "column win"
        for (var row = 0; row < ROW_SIZE - 1; row++) {
            if (board[row][col] != board[row][col + 1] || board[row][col] == -1)
                continue outer;
        }
         alert("Winner");
        return;
    }

    //Same for diagonal
}

var board = makeBoard();

check();
```